# C# and NPOI cant read number and string value

Tags: c#, npoi

I've read a file with NPOI and in one column I have some number values and some char values.  I need to check if this Cell contains a char value (like "stop"), and if so then I don't want to read this.  This is what I've tried:

```
if (sheet.GetRow(row) != null and sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(2).Substr(0,4) != "stop")
{
    Console.Write(sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(1));
}
```

However I can't read char and number values using this code.

Comment: Use a TryParse to see if number, if so then go that route, if not then check if it says "stop".

Comment: Int32.TryParse(sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(1), dummy) dont work, some wrong understand
не удается преобразовать из "NPOI.SS.UserModel.ICell" в "string"

Comment: Summarize the two answers: 1) GetCell() will not directly return you a string or a number. The return is more than that. 2) Using `GetCell().ToString()` will get you the content in string.Then TryParse it to a number. If it works, it is a number. If not, it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

its bit tricky. See the below approach to read the value. Convert your read value into string object like  this **sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(1).ToString();**

```
 XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow)sheet.GetRow(i);
     for (int j = row.FirstCellNum; j < cellCount; j++)
     {
            if (null != row.GetCell(j) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.GetCell(j).ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.GetCell(j).ToString()))
             {
                Console.Write(row.GetCell(j).ToString());
             }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetCell()` method returns `ICell` interface which contains property `StringCellValue`

So, use this property and try your logic on this string.

Comment: im tried this 
if (sheet.GetRow(row) != null && Int32.TryParse(sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(1).StringCellValue,out dummy) == false ) 
and get 
System.InvalidOperationException: "Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell"

Comment: try this
if (sheet.GetRow(row) != null && Int32.TryParse(sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(1).NumericCellValue,out dummy) == false )

Comment: In your code, I see that you just `Console.Write(sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(1));`. Have you tried adding the `.ToString()`, like `Console.Write(sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(1).ToString();`? If I have to get the cell content and don't know if it is a number of string, I would use GetCell().ToString() to get the content as string. I will then try parse to number. If it works, it is a number. If not, you know that is a string.